# Close window by clicking background area in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-ui

I want to close the opened window by clicking on the gray background.

[image]

But when I click on the window itself, it does not close

Comment: What grey button. I see a blue window on a grey background. What code did you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a button that occupies the entire screen behind the red mark button. Set this button's background to none and add an onclick event just as this red mark button